# How go get entry from last year MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

This part of the query doesn't seem to be working

```
$iThisYear = date('Y');
$iLastYear = $iThisYear-1;

SELECT * FROM `{$this->_sPrefix}clicks` 
WHERE `affiliate_id` = '{$iAid}' 
AND `raw` = '1' 
AND YEAR(`date`) = '{$iLastYear}'
```

It grabs from this year still.  Does YEAR work?

Comment: Well, what does `YEAR` contain?

Comment: I found the problem.  Year does work, my switch wasn't finished...

Comment: please mark the question as resolved or delete it then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Could you use DATE_SUB instead

```
SELECT * FROM `{$this->_sPrefix}clicks` 
WHERE `affiliate_id` = '{$iAid}' 
AND `raw` = '1' 
AND YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use DATE_SUB

```
.... where yourdate_column > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH)
```

Answer (score 0):

date('Y') returns a string. You might be running into a problem trying to subtract 1 from a string. You should try subtracting a year's worth of seconds from your timestamp and get that Year. I could be wrong because I know php is loosely typed, and I can't get my xampp working atm to test it. Good luck bud

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

`AND year = YEAR( NOW() ) - 1`

Answering this for future reference.

Good luck!!